# Acess Denied for User root@local in Laravel to connect mysql but Mysql is Connected in Express.js?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYr6r.png)

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = Roshan and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:822
    818▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    819▕                 );
    820▕             }
    821▕ 
  ➜ 822▕             throw new QueryException(
    823▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    824▕             );
    825▕         }
    826▕     }

      +35 vendor frames 

  36  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

Comment: Well you are missing quotes around 2 of the text values in the query

Comment: That error normally means you have the wrong password

Comment: also this can also mean you may need necessary privileges to access the specified database.